# Populating a tableview with child objects of parent entity

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two tableviewcontrollers in a navigation controller hierarchy. The first contains parent entities, which I have successfully populated from a core data entity fetch request. I created a one-to-many relationship in the parent entity to the child entity and seem to be adding child entities okay. I can populate it with all the children of all the parents, but can't restrict it to the current parent. I have tried using predicates in the child tableview controller fetch request but without success.

Should I be using includesSubEntities and keeping the parent entity used in the request? If so, would I use the delegate protocol in some way?

The code below is for the child tableview. The commented-out bits are different attempts!

Thanks.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchSerials
{
    if ( !_fetchSerials )
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity =
        [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Serial"
                    inManagedObjectContext:AppDelegatePtr.managedObjectContext];
  //      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inExercise.name = '%@'", [[SMNetworkModel sharedInstance] selectedNarrative]];
    //    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    //    [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"inExercise"]];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"narrative" ascending:YES];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
        _fetchSerials = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:AppDelegatePtr.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        _fetchSerials.delegate = self;
        NSError *error;
        if ( ![_fetchSerials performFetch:&error] )
            NSLog(@"fetch error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    return _fetchSerials;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stupid typo combined with a shortfall in my understanding of my new friend Core Data was all that was stopping Predicates from working.

I had mistakenly thought you passed objectIds around instead of the objects themselves.

Uncomment the two lines involving the predicate and change the selectedNarrative to the correct property and it all worked!